# Angular with Rails and Google Authenticator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, google-authenticator

I'm Building a website using Ruby on Rails + AngularJS + [devise token auth Gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and I want to implement [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en).

I Found this gem [devise_google_authenticator](https://github.com/AsteriskLabs/devise_google_authenticator)

The problem is that I cannot implement the Gem because I'm using AngularJS.

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem that Angular causes? Does your Gem return HTML  or JSON? Do you need Angular to power your authentication form?

Comment: devise token auth Gem "JSON" yes i need Angular to power your authentication form ...

Comment: Then where is the problem? Angular can handle JSON and is completely decoupled from the server.

Comment: this doesn't really helps. Just try to describe what you're currently doing and where you get some errors, issues etc. Maybe look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423383/how-to-keep-globally-current-user-until-logout-with-angular-devise?noredirect=1#comment47480602_29423383 where it is about rails, angular , device Gem and angular-devise . Maybe it helps